# HTTP 504 Error - IIS - ASP.Net Application

Tags: iis

I created an ASP.net application, published it through IIS on local machine and it's working perfect at the same machine or others on the same network.
The problem is when i deployed the application to a server and tried to access through http, if the page takes more than 60 seconds to respond (which is normal in my case) i get HTTP 504 Error - Page not working. However code completes to run normally in the backend.
I tried the below solution and other several solutions but all in vain.

Appreciate any help.